# Ajax POST blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: python, ajax, flask, header, cors

Hi I've been scrambling the web for hours now trying to find a solution.

I'm trying to make a post request to my own web server hosted by Namecheap.

Here's my Ajax code to call the Post request. Note: I can't show the url sorry.

```
             $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.someurl.com/something" + avariable + "/" + anotherthing,
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                    console.log(resp)
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });
```

This was a code i got from another stackoverflow post's answer which had the most upvotes. It didn't seem to work. actually all of them didn't work.

I'm calling this ajax from a index.html I have running on my localhost.

And i got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'the url i cant show' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any help would be much appericiated! I've never encountered this issue before and I don't know how to handle it.

**Update 1**
I have access to the backend server. Its running Flask on Python.

Any ideas how I can enable the CORS thing there?

Also I'm not sure what the origin of this index.html will be. Because I'll be packaging it into an `electron js` desktop application.

Comment: You need an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the API target server

Comment: Check with your web server hosting if they have option to enable CORS policy.

Comment: My backend is running python flask. Any idea how i can add it there?

Comment: @Denise check my answer, i haven't tested it but it should work with some tuning based on your backend code

Comment: @Denise also check the updates if you need CORS only for development. Browser extensions can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `flask-cors` in your flask app:

`pip install -U flask-cors`

Then in your code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route("/something+avariable/anotherthing")
@cross_origin()
def yourfunction():
```

Alternatively, add it manually:

```
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

If you need it for development only then you can use a CORS browser extension such as **[this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)** for Chrome and **[this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)** for FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

CORS stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

Its just a mechanism to block unauthorized request to a server.

On your backend you will have yo authorize the address you are using to access your backend.

For php:

Comment: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");